# How Yahoo Mail login page could store cookie on some different path on user's system?

Tags: security, yahoo-mail, login, authentication

Some time ago in Yahoo Mail's login page, there was an option to keep signature as text or image on user's system. So even after user logged out and come back again, can see the signature on the same system. I have tried to find out at that time and found something that yahoo puts cookie for that in different path. If it's correct then, how it can be done?
Now, I don't see such signature option on yahoo, what should go wrong with that?